# AES256 CBC encryption in java failing intermittently during Load Test

Tags: java, multithreading, cryptography

I'm using a java code to encrypt input data(AES256 CBC). Attached the code FYR.
Works fine but during load test for more than 20 concurrent users, 1 in every 50 requests gives an unexpected result(encryption is not correct).
I know this because in the load test, inputs for all requests are the same.

I've already tried using synchronize blocks here but still not success.

```java
public static String getEncryptedValue(String myKey, String value) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    synchronized(value) {

        //Declarations
        SecretKeySpec secretKey;
        byte[] key;
        String encryptedString = "";

        MessageDigest sha = null;

        key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // use only first 128 bit
        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            encryptedString = (Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(value.trim().getBytes("UTF-8"))));
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }

        return Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedString.getBytes());
    }
}
```

There are no Error messages or stdErr logs as well. Just an invalid result.

Comment: How do you execute this static method concurrently?

Comment: Doesn't look like a concurrency issue (in the code shown, there may be issues elsewhere), if the variables really are local. The `synchronized` block is completely useless, and synchronizing on `value` is just as useless.

Comment: @LutzHorn -- I call this method from a middleware tool(IBM Integration Bus) as an external procedure call which allows concurrency of requests.

Comment: @Kayaman -- Should i Synchornize on the variable "encryptedString" ? The Variables should ideally be local as per definition. If not synchornized blocks, what else can be done? Like how do we maintain a state where threads don't intertwine?

Comment: In the given code there's no need for synchronization at all. The variables are local, so they're thread-safe by definition. Unless you're doing something strange **outside** of `getEncryptedValue` (such as overwriting the results in a non-threadsafe way, causing data corruption), it's not a concurrency issue.

Comment: @Kayaman -- Its the return value of getEncryptedValue that i use directly. During Load, discrepancy is observed in the value returned that too intermittently. I know this because all requests are the input values are same in the load. That's why i'm assuming its a concurrency issue. Any suggestions what i can do here?

Comment: You can show the code that calls `getEncryptedValue` and what it does with it. Also the relevant code where you're doing things with multiple threads.

Comment: @Kayaman -- the code that calls and uses the result is an ESQL code(used in IBM IIB tool). This method call is like an external java procedure call.

Comment: Then compare the correctly encrypted value and the wrongly encrypted value. Are they completely different? If you decode the wrongly encrypted value, what do you get (i.e. an exception or just a garbled value)?

Comment: @Kayaman -- Yeah. The values are completely different. That's how the issue came up?

Comment: If you decode the wrongly encrypted value, what do you get (i.e. an exception or just a garbled value)? Also, why are you Base64 encoding `encryptedString` twice? You're also missing the encoding in the second `getBytes()`, that's a bad thing (although unrelated to this problem).

Comment: instead of UTF-8 use base64

Comment: @Kayaman -- You were right, the problem was not a concurrency issue at java but at the calling application side. We fixed that and now the code works fine without the Synchronized block as well. Well check these inputs you've given too.